# I need to convert any input of hex characters to ASCII using While loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, hex, ascii

I want my while loop to continue asking me for an input after displaying each ASCII output and stop asking by entering "done".

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Practice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter a String");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String hex = input.nextLine();
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
         while (!input.equals("done")){
             for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i+=2) {
                 String str = hex.substring(i, i+2);
                 output.append((char)Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
             }
         }
             System.out.println(output);
     }

}



The result I want to get:
Enter a string
Input:25
Output:%
Enter a string 
Input:done
program terminated!
```

Comment: Hello on StackOverflow! Could you try to be more precise in what is wrong with your code? Maybe even with an example of your input and desired output?

Comment: unfortunately the result I get is: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
 at loops.Practice.main(Practice.java:15)

Comment: Yes! Please see my answer discussing your infinite loop. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public class Practice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter a String");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String hex = "";
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    while((hex = input.nextLine()) != "done"){
        for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i+=2) {
          System.out.println("Enter a String");
          String str = hex.substring(i, i+2);
            output.append((char)Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
         }
          System.out.println(output);
     }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've built an infinite loop with that piece of code:

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //...
         while (!input.equals("done")){
             for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i+=2) {
                 String str = hex.substring(i, i+2);
                 output.append((char)Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
             }
         }
```

Your while loop continues until `input` is not equal to "done". However inside the loop `input` will never change and thus the the for-statement is repeatedly executed forever (or you decide to stop the program - which is more likely) [Edit: Ok, an OutOfMemory-Exception is within the realm of possibility too]

I usually solve such problems with a `while(true)`-loop and a carefully placed `if(stop-condition){break;}`. Something like this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      while(true){
          //…
          //while (!input.equals("done")){
          if(hex.equals("done"){ break; }
          for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i+=2) {
              String str = hex.substring(i, i+2);
              output.append((char)Integer.parseInt(str, 16));
          }
          System.out.println(output);
     }
     System.out.println("Quitting program (you may applaud now)");
```

Also note you want to use `hex.equals()` rather than `input.equals` as input is a Scanner and it's `equals()` is not what you want here.

Comment: I'm in the process of putting these guys together so I'll find out how to make it work..have no results yet..but thanks again!

Comment: I'll let u no if I got success

Comment: You're very welcome! You can also edit your question if further (related) problems arise ~ and mark my answer as accepted if it was helpful :)

Comment: hey I found the solution !